# Why prohibit a function object in function position (but allow lambda forms)?

Tags: lambda, syntax, common-lisp

#### lambda <s>form</s> expression in function position

A lambda expression in function position compiles just fine:

```
> ((lambda (n) (> n 10)) 42)
T
```

#### Closure built from a lambda in function position

On the other hand:

```
> (defun greater-than (x)
     (lambda (n) (> n x)))
GREATER-THAN

> ((greater-than 10) 42)
Compile-time error:  illegal function call
```

doesn't work.

(I obviously need to call `FUNCALL` to make it work: `(funcall (greater-than 10) 42)` => `T`.

### Why this design?

I understand why a SYMBOL with a function object as *value binding* must not work, e.g.: `(let ((foo (lambda () 42))) (foo))`. Separate namespaces and all that.

But why prohibit a function object itself in function position? What was the rationale behind this decision?

Comment: [hysterical raisins](http://catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What is a lambda form?**

> A lambda-form in function position compiles just fine:

In Common Lisp wording a [lambda expression](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#lambda_expression) is not a [form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#form). A list with a *lambda expression* and zero or more arguments is a *form*, specifically a *lambda form*. Forms can be evaluated, *lambda expressions* not. Note: there is also a macro operator `lambda`, which expands the *macro form* `(lambda ...)` into `(function (lambda ...))` - which is a valid form, using the *special operator* `function`.

```
(                       ; the whole list is a valid lambda form

 (lambda (n) (> n 10))   ; a lambda expression, not a form

 42)                     ; 42 is a form, too
```

The lambda form above is mostly similar to:

```
(let ((n 42))
  (> n 10))
```

**Calling function objects of evaluation results at runtime**

> But why prohibit a function object itself in function position? What was the rationale behind this decision?

Common Lisp prefers to have known (or unknown) functions in function position.

```
(sin 3)
((lambda (x) (sin 3)) 3)
(unknown-function 3)
```

Above all three functions can't be anything else: they can't be numbers, strings or other data objects. There is no way to put another data object there. Operators like `DEFUN`, `FLET` and others refuse to define functions, which are of some other data type (numbers, strings, ...).

If we would have a computation in function position we could write:

```
((if (> foo bar) 42 #'sin) 3)
```

Depending on the evaluation of `(> foo bar)` this could be similar to `(sin 3)` or `(42 3)`, where the latter is not a valid form, since a number is not a function.

Common Lisp requires one to explicitly use one of `FUNCALL`, `APPLY`, `MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL` to call function objects. This makes it clear in the source code that a function object is being computed/retrieved and called. They also do the necessary checks that the thing passed really is a function or a symbol denoting a function.

**Background**

For some details see [Technical Issues of Separation in Function Cells and Value Cells by Gabriel/Pitman](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Technical-Issues.html).

Comment: All good answers. I chose this one because of the `(if (> foo bar) 42 #'sin)` example. I know this follow up question is primarily opinion based so I hide it in the commen section: Do you think it was a good design choice? I mean, yes, as a programmer you can screw up like in your `(if (...) 42 #'sin)` example but it's not like common lisp is that strict in all other areas (no compile time type checking).

Comment: @Frank: personally I support the idea that explicit FUNCALL, etc. makes code more maintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 6):

Mostly, “historical reasons”, i. e., implementation issues, but it also is not semantically obvious with respect to the separation of function and value namespace.  The form in operator position is evaluated to its *function value*.  Only symbols have a *function value*.

`Lambda` forms are a special case; you might imagine them to evaluate to a function in both function and value namespace.  However, this is not *actually correct*, just an approximation/rationalization.

When I was younger, I imagined that there should be a reader macro mirroring `#'`, for example `#^`, so that you could “pull” something into the function namespace, just as you “pull” something into the value namespace with `#'`.  However, it would just expand to `funcall`:

`(#^(make-adder 5) 3)` ≡ `(funcall (make-adder 5) 3)`

I am nowadays very reluctant to introduce reader macros for such frivolous uses.  Relax, just use funcall, it really works out quite nicely in the end.

Answer (score 4):

## Namespace confusion argument

The whole two namespace nature of Common Lisp has its benefits and its downsides. The benefit and the reason CL predecessor  got two namespaces is that it is simpler to make compilers and efficient code. This is ancient history and a crucial CL design choice.

When your code has a form that has a symbol or lambda it can be compiled to machine code very easily.

The second you want to allow compound expressions to return functions that then is applied you cannot determine this compile time anymore (at least not always and at least not in the 70s) and thus you need all the features of `funcall` even without using it in code. You could perhaps make a macro that adds the `funcall` automatically but I feel learning the dual namespace of Common Lisp would be even harder than it already is today for beginners.

## Performance argument

Now it is obvious that `(+ 2 3)` is guaranteed to be equal and most times more efficient than `(funcall #'+ 2 3)` even though it's clear from looking at them that they both are the same and very static. Perhaps if we didn't need to write `funcall` we would use this looser style much more often and the result would be less performant code by default. This is perhaps true for Scheme where you often see

```
((if (some-fun ..) 
     fun1 
     fun2) 
 3 
 4)
```

..rather than the possibly more optimizable:

```
(if (some-fun ..)
    (fun1 3 4)
    (fun2 3 4))
```

In CL it might be easier to choose the second choice since the first would look like:

```
(funcall (if (some-fun ..) 
             #'fun1
             #'fun2) 
         3 
         4)
```

I don't really like this argument since one should never micro-optimize for the sake of performance. It perhaps make code harder to read, longer to write, and gives no real speed improvement.